# Передача данных на форму через DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

Есть 3 класса и под каждый из классов сделана привязка через DataBinding для передачи данных на форму, и 4й главный обобщающий куда занесены данные с предыдущих 3х классов.
Сделал через LINQ запрос и создал новую коллекцию

```
List<UserInfo> mainClass = new List<UserInfo>();
var selectedItems = from item in mainClass select new {
    item.Person.Name, item.Person.Surname,
    item.Address.Street, item.Address.House,
     item.Phone.Number,  item.Email };
```

Подскажите, как мне через привязку DataBinding вывести на форму 4й класс, только чтобы выводило не сами поля главного класса, а полностью все как в анонимном через LINQ запрос?[image: Чтобы вы понимали всю суть задания]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: А это как выводит у меня основной DataGrid]

```
    List<Main> mainClass = new List<Main>();
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var selectedItems = from item in mainClass select new {
            Person = item.Person.FIO + item.Person.Gender + item.Person.YearOfBirth,
            Address = item.Address.Street + item.Address.House + item.Address.Apartment,
            Phone = item.Phone.Number + item.Phone.TypePhone,
            item.Email };

        bindingSource.DataSource = selectedItems;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чем не устроил биндинг на анонимный класс? Как вариант, сделать у главного класса свойства для чтения полей вложенных сущностей.

Comment: вот он меня и интересует, как мне это все вывести анонимный класс в форму на датагрид?

Comment: Создаете BindingSource (он умеет работать с IEnumerable), кладете в него результат LiNQ-запроса, а сам BindingSource используете для биндинга к форме. Только у анонимного класса поля сделайте именованными. Так не работает или не пробовали?

Comment: я так понимаю так ?: List<Main> mainClass = new List<Main>();
        BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();var selectedItems = from item in mainClass select new {
                Person = item.Person.FIO + item.Person.Gender + item.Person.YearOfBirth,
                Address = item.Address.Street + item.Address.House + item.Address.Apartment,
                Phone = item.Phone.Number + item.Phone.TypePhone,
                item.Email }; bindingSource.DataSource = selectedItems; dataGridView.DataSource = bindingSource;

Comment: попробуйте и посмотрите что получится. Вообще код лучше добавлять в вопрос, в комментариях его читать очень тяжело. Навскидку вижу проблему со склеенными строками, между словами очевидно пробел ожидается... Если не получится, возьму ваш код за основу и посмотрю что не так в студии. В вопросе должен быть минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему, а если получится, сами и напишете ответ =)

Comment: так биндил уже, оно биндит но не в том виде что мне нужно, нужно чтобы в DataGrid выводило все колонки фио, гендер, дата, улица и тд, оно биндит уже Person Address Phone Email и при вызове второй формы для заполнения данных на нее передаются все поля для заполнения. Сложно обьяснить суть задания вот так на словах)

Comment: ну так объясните кодом + можно приложить скрин с видом грида и на его основе объяснить как он должен выглядеть. Вопрос можно [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1014576/edit)

Comment: выложил скрин с заданием, чтобы было представление какая суть задания и выложил скрин как выводит в датагриде колонки, в задании показано как должно быть

Comment: Замените запрос из конструктора формы, на тот, что привели в начале вопроса. Только дайте имена полям анонимного класса для отображения в заголовке грида.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду FIO = t.Person.FIO, Gender = t.Person.Gender и тд. ? Или я что-то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: Правильно понимаете

Comment: А привязка у меня правильная?

Comment: Раз работает, значит правильная :) только данных правильных не хватало

Comment: добавил в конец скриншот. Вот так у меня получилось и в DataGride ничего не выводит, что-то я делаю не так..(

Comment: dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

Comment: спасибо за помощь, вроде как немного разобрался, и если можно еще один вопросик) как мне сохранить содержимое датагрида в XML-файл(сериализация) после закрытия программы(формы) и наоборот при загрузке формы данные подтягивались из файла?

Comment: Зачем вам сериализовать грид, у вас же есть модельные объекты из которых вы гриды заполняете, вот их и сериализуйте

Comment: немного не понял, если можно поподробней

Comment: Один вопрос - одна тема, это местные правила Попробуйте, опишите что не получается в отдельном вопросе.

Comment: понял, еще раз спасибо!